# How can I find out what version of bluetooth my laptop supports?

Tags: windows-7, bluetooth

Is there a place in Windows I can see this? I want to know if it supports bluetooth 3, and the specs are difficult to find!

Comment: Only the specifications of your laptop would answer this question.

Comment: Make and model may assist in an answer.

Answer (score 28):

First, go to Control Panel and open "Device Manager" (or just search for it from the Start Menu). From there, click the dropdown next to Bluetooth and locate the Bluetooth adapter for your device. (It will be the item that does *not* have "Enumerator" in its name.) In my case, it's "Bluetooth USB Module":

[image: Device Manager]

Right-click this item and select "Properties". Then go to the "Advanced" tab and note the LMP (link management protocol) version displayed for the device:

[image: LMP version 7.602.]

The LMP versions correspond to Bluetooth versions as follows:

- LMP 0.x - Bluetooth 1.0b
- LMP 1.x - Bluetooth 1.1
- LMP 2.x - Bluetooth 1.2
- LMP 3.x - Bluetooth 2.0 + EDR
- LMP 4.x - Bluetooth 2.1 + EDR
- LMP 5.x - Bluetooth 3.0 + HS
- LMP 6.x - Bluetooth 4.0
- LMP 7.x - Bluetooth 4.1
- LMP ​8.x - ​Bluetooth 4.2
- LMP 9.x - Bluetooth 5.0

Sources:

- [What version of the Bluetooth standard does my computer / laptop / tablet support?](http://www.bluetoothandusb3.com/how-to-confirm-bluetooth-version-of-computer)
- [The Bluetooth Spec - Link Manager Version Parameter](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/assigned-numbers/link-manager)

Comment: +1 for when this works, but unfortunately for me I only get this on my laptop:
https://i.imgur.com/TiXqdw2.png

Comment: (Just in case anyone points out, I appreciate in the image I linked above it says "Bluetooth 4.1" in the name of the device :D but this is just a fortunate naming of Dell's bluetooth adapter, obviously I want something that would work consistently on any computer)

Comment: And what does the "x" part signify?

Comment: @ThomasW "x" in this case can be anything. The important part is the major version number.

Comment: @Ajedi32 I understand, but I doubt that it simply means anything. I'm curious what the "x" means _exactly_

Answer (score 2):

Right click on "My Computer" (desktop) -> Device manager -> expand to see the bluetooth driver.
In my case it is "Bluetooth v3.0".

Comment: yes, my mistake

Comment: aparently microsoft has a guide on testing this, but you need two computers with bluetooth https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh998565.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Go to Device Manager > Bluetooth > Right Click on {your_bluetooth_device} > Properties > Details tab >
[Bluetooth Radio LMP version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCniv.png) > [Value field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRKTC.png).

In my case it was 0A (HEX) -> 10 (decimal) which means Bluetooth 5.1 if you match against this  [Link Manager Protocol Versions list](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/what-bluetooth-version-is-on-my-pc-f5d4cff7-c00d-337b-a642-d2d23b082793).

Answer (score 0):

Mine appears in "system information" under network adapter as Adapter Type: Ethernet 802.3
Is that what you need?

Comment: Does `Ethernet 802.3` mean Bluetooth 3?

Comment: I don't think so. According to the Wiki Bluetooth 3 uses 802.11 - mine is just Bluetooth 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to Start -> Control Pannel -> System (type in the search box) -> Advance System Settings -> Hardware Tab -> Device Manager -> Bluetooth Radios -> Properties -> Details -> Bus reported device description (find in the list box) -> read "value".

Comment: And look for what...? (btw if you use the search box anyway, you can just type *"device manager"* in the Start search box)

Comment: There is no device property which will show you the version in the device manager.

Comment: Look for what is requested by the OP. Searching in the box might be a shortcut. I pasted what I know, I am no windows expert.

Comment: I never saw this post somehow, but I just had a look and you were right at least in this case, +1, but I'll need to confirm on at least two more, different devices before I would mark as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to look up your device with the manufacturer to see what is supported by your device. The device may have more capabilities than your OS or device permits. This information will not be reported as a value in the Device Manager.

You should be able to determine if all of the needed profiles are present by looking through the various bluetooth setting by going to the Bluetooth Control Panel, which you can launch directly using the following shortcut in your Run menu or Start menu search `%windir%\explorer.exe shell:::{28803F59-3A75-4058-995F-4EE5503B023C}`

You may also want to check out this page on what versions of [bluetooth are supported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn133849%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in Windows 7:

> ```
> Version 1.1 
> Version 2.0
> Version 2.0 with EDR*
> Version 2.1 with EDR*
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Bluetooth Version finder v1.0

[Bluetooth Version finder v1.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UqFZU.png)

You can use a Portable freeware “Bluetooth Version finder v1.0”  to find your Bluetooth version easily
https://www.sordum.org/10772/bluetooth-version-finder-v1-0/

Comment: Error: Windows version not supported when running on Windows 7.