# How to know the bluetooth verion in my laptop by CMD or PowerShell

Tags: windows-10, powershell, cmd.exe, bluetooth

As [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1064343/674019), I know how to find the version of my built-in **Bluetooth** device. But could we just by **CMD** or **PowerShell** do know such information?

Comment: Have you tried `systeminfo.exe` on command prompt?

Comment: @Sandeep [It will provide Bluetooth version information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKtwl.png)?

Comment: Well, you know you could just type it and see...

Answer (score 2):

Try...

```
# Very basic stuff
($SysInfo = systeminfo) -match 'bluetooth'

# get all NIC details
(Get-NetAdapter | Select-Object -Property *) -match 'bluetooth'

MacAddress                                       : A4-34-D9-71-B3-DE
Status                                           : Disconnected
LinkSpeed                                        : 3 Mbps
MediaType                                        : 802.3
PhysicalMediaType                                : BlueTooth
AdminStatus                                      : Up
MediaConnectionState                             : Disconnected
DriverInformation                                : Driver Date 2006-06-21 Version 10.0.17134.1 NDIS 6.30
DriverFileName                                   : bthpan.sys
NdisVersion                                      : 6.30
...
```

*** Updated - as per the OP last request ***

Yes it does, however let's see if we can do better.

See this module...

> Device Management PowerShell Cmdlets Sample – An introduction
>   'blogs.technet.microsoft.com/wincat/2012/09/06/device-management-powershell-cmdlets-sample-an-introduction'
>
> 'gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Device-Management-7fad2388'

```
Import-Module -Name DeviceManagement
(Get-Device | Select-Object Name,DriverVersion,DriverProvider,DriverDescription) -match 'bluetooth'

# Results

Name                                      DriverVersion DriverProvider     DriverDescription                        
----                                      ------------- --------------     -----------------                        
Intel(R) Wireless Bluetooth(R)            19.71.0.2     Intel Corporation  Intel(R) Wireless Bluetooth(R)           
...          
Bluetooth LE Device                      
Bluetooth Device (RFCOMM Protocol TDI)    10.0.17134.1  Microsoft          Bluetooth Device (RFCOMM Protocol TDI


(Get-Driver | Select-Object *) -match 'bluetooth'

# Results

...

Description      : Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network)
ManufacturerName : Microsoft
ProviderName     : Microsoft
DriverDate       : 20-Jun-06 17:00:00
DriverVersion    : 10.0.17134
...

Description      : Standard Bluetooth Modem
ManufacturerName : Standard Cell Phones
ProviderName     : Microsoft
DriverDate       : 20-Jun-06 17:00:00
DriverVersion    : 10.0.17134

Description      : Edimax Wi-Fi N150 Bluetooth4.0 USB Adapter
ManufacturerName : Edimax Technology Co., Ltd.
ProviderName     : Microsoft
DriverDate       : 25-Oct-16 17:00:00
DriverVersion    : 1030.11.503

Description      : 802.11g MiniUSB 2.0 Wireless Bluetooth Combo
ManufacturerName : Ralink Technology Corp.
ProviderName     : Microsoft
DriverDate       : 01-Oct-11 17:00:00
DriverVersion    : 4.0.10
```

Comment: It have any information about Bluetooth version?