# How to know which version of the hands-free profile is supported by Bluetooth adapter?

Tags: bluetooth, adapter, headset

This [excellent question](https://superuser.com/questions/502825/how-can-i-find-out-what-version-of-bluetooth-my-laptop-supports) shows how you can know what version Bluetooth your adapter supports. However, something that is important for wireless headsets is the Hands-Free Profile (HFP) version. HFP 1.5 has 8 kHz audio when microphone is on, while HFP 1.7 has 16 kHz audio in this case. HFP 1.7 also shows battery levels of connected devices.

However, I can't seem to figure out what HFP version is supported by my Bluetooth adapter. Where can I find this?

Comment: Did you figure out a way to get the HFP version ?

Comment: @Guru nope, I don't think it is possible to see. I have only found it on the datasheets from the manufacturers until now...